Last apt update && apt upgrade 'killed' my Linux partitions - any way to recover the disk layout?
Some 10 days ago I made the release upgrade to 24.4.1, successfully. Some restarts later, with the last apt upgrade (6.8.0-40-generic to 6.8.0-41-generic), which went through properly, too, and one more 'Sleep', it bailed out after the 'Wake Up' with initramfs.
Booted to the 24.04.1 Live-CD, and found that except of /boot, everything else that used to be '/' and 'home' before, is noted as 'unallocated'. Consequently, at boot it bails out with the root partition not found.
I pretty much think that the data are still there, only by some strange coincidence at 'Sleep'-'Wake Up' (that used to work for years here, with earlier versions without incidence) the information of the disk geometry (extended partitions) must have got lost.
The drive is a SSD, SanDisk SSD PLUS 1000 GB, and shows good SMART status, Healthy, and Success at Self tests.
I wonder if there is any chance to recover / reinstate the partitions? They were all sub-partitions in the extended partition /dev/sda4; out of which only the /boot is left over.


You might like to try using Disktest from the Ubuntu install media. (You need to test the disk unmounted.) https://thelinuxcode.com/install-testdisk-ubuntu-22-04/

Is this a Ubuntu tool or a Windows tool that generated the picture of the disk info?

related omgubuntu article and also this discourse post

@David DE: This is the easiest of all comments to answer to: KDE Partition Manager and Spectacle.

@graham: Thanks, but unclear how it relates to my question. The update went through without a hitch; a downgrade isn't envisaged.
What saddens me, is that for the last cycles, the release upgrades have been riddled with ever more trouble. First, wait for the dot-release, postponed to end of August, taken in, now enabled once again.
Should I have overlooked a specific hint to my troubles, please correct me.

I understand your frustration but don't shoot the messenger! I'm simply passing on what I have understood to be an issue which possibly might have impacted you as a starting point. I don't profess to have the answers.

@david Phantastic! - It took some time, but all partitions popped up again, and I could Write the partition table back, reboot, and everything is there, once again. Thanks a big bunch!

Thanks to @david, the process of using testdisk from a 24.4.1-Live-CD, installable after a sudo apt update, brought back all previous partitions and files (as far as I can see) almost automatically. Now it looks once again like before.
